# MATLAB: Make plotted lines distinguishable maximally

Tags: matlab

Do you know a way to somehow make plotted lines in MATLAB distinguishable at the maximum? I know about generating maximal distinguishable colors via [this nice function from the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors) but if the lines are very close together like in the following, it's still very tough to distinguish them. Probably not possible other then scaling the axis logarithmically, is it!?

[image]

Edit: Image URL for a better view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIF1E.png

Comment: If your data are close together, I don't think any amount of formatting can change that ;) That particular data looks very appropriate for a log axis to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple function to implement [Luis Mendo's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923817/matlab-make-plotted-lines-distinguishable-maximally#comment31415885_20923846):

```
function out = interleaveFuncs(len,varargin)
% input lines must be column vectors, so they would be plotted correctly
% each input can contain more than one column (line) though
out = cat(2,varargin{:});
sz = size(out);
out(sub2ind(sz, 1:sz(1) ,mod(floor([0:sz(1)-1]/len),len)+1)) = nan;
```

Use like this:

```
a=[1:10].';
plot(a,interleaveFuncs(3,[a a+1],a+2));
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *color*, you can distinguish the lines by *marker* type (`'o'`, `'.'`, ...) and *line* type (`'-'`, `'--'`, ...). For example:

```
plot(x1,y1,'o--','color',color1)
plot(x2,y2,'+-.','color',color2)
```

Another possibility (as indicated in the comments): you could apply some "gating" to the functions: for example, `y1.*[1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 ...]`, `y2.*[NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN...]`. You will get color-striped lines, each with a hole where the other is visible.

Comment: Ah sorry to not have stated this: Yeah I know it but then it even becomes more "crowded". Further I'd love to see some sort of framework to automatically chose the appropriate marker type as I use the plot-command within a for-loop.

Comment: You could perhaps apply some "gating" to the functions: for example, `y1.*[1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 ...]`,  `y2.*[NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN...]`. You will get color-striped lines, each with a hole where the other is presents

Comment: Actually that's a nice idea :-) Thanks for that, I'm trying it out